# Diamond operator and additional types in dynamic type

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've asked myself if the diamond operator also works if not all types of the dynamic type are also given in the static type.

Look at the code: If I need the type C for a method in "Class", but I use "Interface" as static type and use the diamond operator, would that be a problem?

```java
interface Interface<A, B> {
...
}

class Class<A, B, C> implements Interface<A, B> {
...
}

Interface<A, B> test = new Class<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work just fine, you can instantiate `Class` without any issue. If I assume that the generic type `C` will be initialized through the constructor (or some other way), you may use that reference in your `Interface` method overridden in `Class`.